# Prestashop top menu not showing changes

Tags: module, prestashop

When I make changes to the top menu to show my categories and not the default settings and hit save, the front end doesn't change. I have been fighting with this for 2 days ready to scrap this whole program! Help!

Comment: Did you cleared the cache? If my suggestion doesn't work, I don't think you will receive an attention from stackoverflow comunnity with such a one-line question. Please to provide details and try to talk more about the problem.Good luck

Comment: I did clear the cache yes. How exactly can I be more specific, I make changes to the topmenu in the backend and it doesn't show a change on the front end. Seems clear to me!

Comment: like for example: prestashop version,  the name of the module( I think there are maybe many default ones, and many commercial ones). I am a beginner in prestashop who only tried to convey my experience with one-line questions asked on SO. If i find other suggestions i ll be posting them here.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to clear the cache manually via FTP.